# How to make directive enable/Disable ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created directive in Angular.I am calling popover directive from mybox. i wish to make popover directive Active only after click on Enable button .

I thought for ng-include but incase of directive how can i use ?
Please suggest ....

Fiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/JNqqU/278/

**Directive Code ::**

```
    var bootstrap = angular.module("bootstrap", []);
bootstrap.directive('myBox', function ($compile) {
       return {
            restrict: "E",
            transclude: true,
            template: "<span>Hello In side Box <a href='#' pop-over items='items' title='Mode of transport'>Show Pop over</a> </span>",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var popOverContent;
                if (scope.items) {
                    var html = getTemplate("items");
                    popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope);                    
                }
                var options = {
                    content: popOverContent,
                    placement: "bottom",
                    html: true,
                    title: scope.title
                };
                $(element).popover(options);
            },
            scope: {
                items: '=',
                title: '@'
            }
        };
    });
bootstrap.directive('popOver', function ($compile) {
        var itemsTemplate = "<ul class='unstyled'><li ng-repeat='item in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]'>{{item}}</li></ul>";
        var getTemplate = function (contentType) {
            var template = '';
            switch (contentType) {
                case 'items':
                    template = itemsTemplate;
                    break;
            }
            return template;
        }
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            transclude: true,
            template: "<span ng-transclude></span>",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var popOverContent;
                if (scope.items) {
                    var html = getTemplate("items");
                    popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope);                    
                }
                var options = {
                    content: popOverContent,
                    placement: "bottom",
                    html: true,
                    title: scope.title
                };
                $(element).popover(options);
            },
            scope: {
                items: '=',
                title: '@'
            }
        };
    });
bootstrap.directive( 'dismissPopovers', [ '$http', '$templateCache', '$compile', '$parse', function ( $http, $templateCache, $compile, $parse) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.bind('mouseup', function(e) {
                        var clickedOutside = true;
                        $('.popover-link').each(function() {
                            if ($(this).is(e.target) || $(this).has(e.target).length) {
                                clickedOutside = false;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if ($('.popover').has(e.target).length) {
                            clickedOutside = false;
                        }
                        if (clickedOutside) {
                            $('.popover').prev().click();
                        }
                    });   
                }
            };
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the bootstrap directive to pass it a parameter wether it should display the popver or not. First add a variable to the directive attributes :

Controller :

```
$scope.popOverShouldOpen = whatYouWantThere;
```

Template :

```
<div pop-over pop-over-should-open="popOverShouldOpen"></div>
```

Then add it to the directive scope :

```
 scope: {
            items: '=',
            title: '@',
            popOverShouldOpen: "="
        }
```

Then put "if" statements inside the link function :

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if( scope.popOverShouldOpen === true ){
             var popOverContent;
             if (scope.items) {
                 var html = getTemplate("items");
                 popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope);                    
             }
             var options = {
                 content: popOverContent,
                 placement: "bottom",
                 html: true,
                 title: scope.title
             };
             $(element).popover(options);
            }
        },
```

Or you could simply do this, depending on your context :

```
<div pop-over ng-show="popOverShouldOpen"> Hello there ! </div>
<div ng-hide="popOverShouldOpen"> Hello there ! </div>
```

Of course this last one is a quick hack. For a massive usage prefer the first !

Comment: i want to make one common button for all directive , somehow i have brought this popOverShouldOpen value inside popover directive .controller--> mybox--->popover  but when on click of button i change controller variavle it is not reflected.

Comment: Just add a button to change the value of $scope.popOverShouldOpen : when set to true, with directives defined like that, any pop-over will show. When false, they will not !

Comment: yes that button i have added . and it changes value also . i am stuck at last directive . controller--> mybox--->popover in this chain i am passing variable , {{togg}} inside this value is printed perfectly but inside link attrs.togg  shows variable name which is written in controller . i have used =  to assign value . i wonder in template {{}} inside this it prints true / false but in directive link it is showing wrong

Comment: you don't want to use attrs.togg but scope.togg after having added popOverShouldOpen: "=" in your directive scope definition and <div pop-over pop-over-should-open="togg"></div> in your template !

Comment: actually as i said in-box directive i am taking it in attr.because  i have written pop-over inside mybox . i dont think controller variable can be passed directly into popover as it is inside mybox .   controllerr--->mybox-->popover